# Why do only Indian squirrels have stripes on them?

Tags: belief, ramayana, animals

Why do only Indian squirrels have stripes on their back, whereas squirrels from other countries don't have stripes on their body?

Is this because of Rama? What is the story/belief behind this?

Comment: question was edited...actually i would like to know, Whether i can use this statement as an evidence of rama to defend others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a legend often associated with Ramayana. This episode is not there in *Valmiki Ramayana, Kambaramayanam, Adhyatmaramyana or Ramacharitamanas*. But I know it has been current for a very very long time. I heard it from my  grandmother.

Several popular modern versions of Ramayana in English and our own languages include it.There is a reference to it in a single verse in *Naalaayira Divyaprabandham*. *Tondaradippodi Azhvaar*, who lived in the 8th century AD says in the 27th verse of his *Tirumaalai*:'I am not like the squirrel which tried to help those monkeys which were lifting and moving hills, by itself rolling over in the sea to provide a small block to the flow of the waves. My heart has the strength of trees, but is treacherous. I am unable to use it in the service of Sri Ranganatha. I am just wasting myself!'

Okay so the story goes like this,

[image]

> Prior to the war, the vanara-sena consisting of monkeys and bears were busy building the bridge to Lanka. The construction was heavy-duty work. Some monkeys noticed a squirrel running back and forth in the construction site. They got curious and tried to observe what the squirrel was up to. The little brown squirrel dipped in the sea and rolled on the sands till its body was fully covered with sand. It then ran to the site of construction and shook the sand off its body and ran back to get the next ‘load’ of sand.
>
> Another version of the story says that it carried little pebbles in the mouth. In any case, the impact of its work was minimal; but the little squirrel went about the routine in full earnest. The monkeys found it amusing and started to mock the squirrel and the bears soon joined them in the act. The squirrel was quite upset in being teased and ran straight to Rama to complain. It had to stand tall on its little feet and shout to make itself heard to Rama – quite tall compared to the rodent. Rama heard the squirrel and his heart melted seeing tears in its eyes. He acknowledged the contribution of the squirrel, however small it was, in his efforts to bring Sita back.
>
> Rama ran his fingers on the back of the animal as a gesture of acknowledgement. That movement of Rama’s fingers earned the squirrel its stripes, which are carried even today by the three striped palm squirrels.

[IndianTales](http://indiantales.in/?p=211)

Comment: I know a little variation of story when Hanumana got angry because of squirrel's action, which made there work slow. So he pressed her tail from feet and then she complained to Rama.

Comment: Here it is https://sites.google.com/site/karmasheth/how-squirrels-got-their-stripes

Comment: @AnkitSharma, lots and lots are variations are there... the one I heard from grandmother doesn't involved the *vanaras* making fun of the chipmunks, rather Rama sees them directly doing their part of *setu* building.

Comment: @VineetMenon thanks for your answer. but question was edited...actually i would like to know, Whether i can use this statement as an evidence of rama to defend others. These stripes are because of rama or any biological things happend to squirrels in india.

Comment: @Shankar if you wanted biological perspective then you should ask the same question in biology.SE. I don't think this incidence would prove/disprove existance of Ram, because our myths are constructed over millenia and thus incorporates many 'real' things in the subcontinent. Infact, if you notice Ramayana is literally filled with real geographical, physical, astronomical artifacts. If you are interested, visit http://www.scoopwhoop.com/inothernews/ramayana-actually-happened/. A link which I came across recently.

Comment: Hi @VineetMenon thanks for your link. Even i don't think this incidence would prove/disprove existence of Ram, But this would support some extent(in a debate).

Comment: It's very easy to come up with an evolutionary explanation for the stripe, IMHO.

Comment: @VineetMenon Great link Vineet, I think the idea of Ravanna ruling 10 kingdoms (10 crowns) and later becoming depicted as 10 headed makes a lot of sense. Probably he was known as "he who wears 10 crowns". Wonder what's the real story behind Hanuman though. Anyway, the first comment was funny: "Yash Gadhiya · Top commenter · London exists, Kings Cross station exists hence Harry Potter is true. Let's find platform 9 3/4 to get to Hogwarts."

Comment: This story is from the Ranganatha Ramayana in Telugu

Comment: @a20, the word mentioned is `vanara`, which literally means 'forest dweller'. The association of vanara with ape like creature is a later addition.