# Sri Rama and squirrel.. where did this story originate?

Tags: ramayana, rama, identification-request

There is a famous story about a squirrel helping Sri Rama in building the bridge (Rama setu) to go to Lanka.

A squirrel sees Vanara army accumulating boulders and rocks for the bridge. A squirrel decides to help Sri Rama and picks up sand and pebbles. Sri Rama notices it and appreciates the effort of the squirrel and warmly stroked the back of the squirrel with his fingers. Since then, it is believed that squirrels have three lines on their body.

The moral of the story is to recognise and appreciate the help even when it comes from a small person.

[image: Sri Rama and squirrel]

This story is not a part of Ramayana written by Valmiki and [Ramcharit Manas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramcharitmanas) written by Goswami Tulsidas. These aren't the only versions of Ramayana. There are many other versions by many poets.

**Question:**

What is the origin of this story involving Sri Rama and squirrel?

From which later versions of Ramayana did this story originate?

Related question: [Why do only Indian squirrels have stripes on them?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3356/5212)

Comment: The same squirrel story is mentioned in Sri Ramdas's Paluke Bhangaramayena song, In which he questions Lord Rama " you have shown your Goodness to a squirrel Devotee. Why don't you show it to me?"

Answer (score 9):

Page 139 of [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=BC3l1AbPM8sC&lpg=PA139&dq=ramayana%20squirrel&pg=PA139#v=onepage&q&f=false) says that the first version of the Ramayana that contains the squirrel story is the Ranganatha Ramayanam, the 14th century Telugu version of the Ramayana:

> There are many innovations in this Ramayana.... It narrates [a] moving incident of a squirrel who helped Rama to construct a bridge on the sea. Not necessarily [wwre these] inventions by the poet himself; they could have been appropriated from folk sources[.]

Page 107 of [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=hzdoAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA107&img=1&pgis=1&dq=Squirrel&sig=ACfU3U1x5fJB-wbjg_ry9EoBmYb4b9iBGQ&edge=0) says the same thing.

But the story seems to be considerably older than the 14th century, because one of the Alwars, Thondaradippodi Alwar, alludes to it in [one of his poems](http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1266):

> pOdellAm pOdu koNDu un ponnaDi punaiya mATTEn 
>   teedilA mozhihaL koNDu un tiruguNam Seppa mATTEn | 
>   kAdalAl nenjam anbu kalandilEn adu tannAlE 
>   EdilEn arangarkku ellE en SeivAn tOnrinEnE ||
>
> Nor am I like the humble squirrel which rolled in the sand and helped, when the monkeys pushed big rocks to build a bridge in the ocean. With a heart full of vice, a heart as hard as wood, infamously I labor, without a single service to the Arangam Lord.

Even by modern dating, Thondaradippodi Alwar dates at least to the 8th century.

Comment: Does this mean Thondaradippodi Alwar believed and accepted this story? If it is not mentioned in VR, how can he write? Is this story mentioned in any Puranas?

Comment: @TatTvamAsi Yes, he accepted it, so it may be present in some scripture.  I haven't found it yet though.

Answer (score 8):

So far, I've found the squirrel's story in the [Hindi translation](https://archive.org/stream/Ranganatha.Ramayana#page/n307/mode/2up) of [Ranganātha Rāmāyaṇa](https://archive.org/details/Ranganatha.Ramayana) (RR) and [Kṛttivāsa Rāmāyaṇa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krittivasi_Ramayan). However, I couldn't locate this story in [the original](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.329386/2015.329386.Sri-Ranganatha#page/n1/mode/2up), Telugu version, of RR.

This, from the Hindi tr. of RR:

> [image]

From Kṛttivāsa Rāmāyaṇa:

> #### (45) Squirrel's help in the construction of the bridge
>
> The ten yojana long bridge was to be built with the stones and hills brought by Hanuman. Of these hundred yojanas, long bridge construction of only twenty yojanas was completed which was inaccessible. The demons started coming to have a look at it. Close by there was the group of squirrels. They would jump in the sea water, wet their bodies roll over the sand and then shed the sand over the bridge, which helped in plugging many holes in the bridge. Hanuman saw that many squirrels were roaming about there. He tried to get them out by terrorizing them and being unsuccessful in his attempt he caught hold of them all and then threw them here and there. All the squirrels then went to Rama with a complaint against Hanuman and told Rama that they had been terrorized by Hanuman.(82)
>
> Rama then called for Hanuman and said, "Why have you humiliated the squirrels? All are participating in the construction of the bridge according to their capacity. Hanuman felt ashamed at this. Raghunatha is extremely kind hearted. He then moved (his affectionate) hand over the back of the squirrels. (There is a belief that the marks of Rama's fingers over the back of the squirrels are still visible in the form of the stripes on their back).(83)
>
> All the monkeys then moved on to the bridge. Hanuman said to them, "Listen, O monkeys, do not disturb the squirrels any more."
>
> ...

---

EDIT

I found [another version](https://archive.org/stream/RanganathaRamayanamu/Ranganatha%20Ramayanamu#page/n321/mode/2up) of Ranganātha Rāmāyaṇa (Telugu) which does contain the squirrel episode. So it's possible this is the original and not the one I linked above.

> [image]

Comment: Multiple sources are saying it's present in the Ranganatha Ramayana.  It's possible it's present in some manuscripts of the Ranganatha Ramayana and not others.  In any case, the Ranganatha Ramayana is older than the Krittivasi Ramayana, so if it's really there in the Ranganatha Ramayana that would be the oldest Ramayana it's found in.

Comment: It's there in Krittivasi Ramayana and this version is quite popular in my place. BTW i was not aware that we can also quote from Krittivasi, Jagadrami Ramayanas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan You maybe right. I suspect the version of RR tried to remove some parts that are not part of VR as apparently RR was written based on a copy of VR.

Comment: @Rickross You sure can quote local Rāmāyaṇas in your answers although some users will remind you it's not 'authentic' scripture but you just need to ignore them :P

Comment: @Rickross Yes, you're allowed to quote from vernacular versions of the Ramayana on this site (assuming you provide their meaning in English, of course).

Comment: @sv. Yeah, I'm one of those people who would say they're not authentic scriptures.  But they're still allowed sources on the site.

Comment: @sv Is it really a mouse (for  mooshikam) in Telugu Ramayanam? ; un- Indian chipmunks also have striped backs,.

Comment: @Narasimham No, the Telugu word used is ఉడుత (uduta) which [translates to](https://translate.google.com/#te/en/uduta) 'squirrel'. I've seen all kinds of squirrels - black, brown and gray, with and without stripes. If an American spots an Indian squirrel he's gonna mistake it for a chipmunk. I think the Indian squirrel having 3 lines on its back because Rama waved his hand is just folklore (as indicated in Kṛttivāsa Rāmāyaṇa).

Comment: I was commenting why in telugu,  word mooshikam was used instead of udutha...Yes folklores aplenty.. like the cobras also got U markings on their hood after Krishna's  dance in Kali di.

Comment: @Narasimham Good point. I re-read the whole canto and marked the couple of places ([see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbMAG.png)) where the poet used the word ఉడుత (uduta) - squirrel - and then Rama uses the word mooshikam (mouse) only once. My guess is the poet was just playing with the words to avoid being repetitive.

Comment: @sv. *’I suspect the version of RR tried to remove some parts that are not part of VR as apparently RR was written based on a copy of VR.’* - 1. would you please be able to give some more information on RR being written based on a copy of Valmiki? 2. Also is there an original RR not altered to try and match the current version of Valmiki and where can one find it? Thanks.